# Calculating time difference in C# and saving to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I've been assigned with the task of calculating a time difference only counting working hours. After searching I was able to get this (it's kinda in Portuguese but I think it's understandable) :

```
    if (!txt_data2.Text.Contains("_") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_data2.Text) && txt_data2.Text != null && !txt_hora2.Text.Contains("_") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_hora2.Text) && txt_hora2.Text != null)
            {
                TimeSpan hi = TimeSpan.Parse(txt_horainicio.Text);
                TimeSpan hf = TimeSpan.Parse(txt_hora2.Text);

                if (hi.Hours < 9 || hf.Hours > 18)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Horas Inválidas");
                }

                else
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Inserir horas extraordinárias?", "Horas Extraordinárias", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        double extra;
                        TimeSpan horasextra;

                        Frm_Tempo frm1 = new Frm_Tempo();

                        if (frm1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            horasextra = TimeSpan.Parse(frm1.txt_horasextra.Text);
                            extra = horasextra.TotalHours;

                            DateTime data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_datainicio.Text);
                            TimeSpan hora1 = TimeSpan.Parse(txt_horainicio.Text);
                            DateTime dataentrega1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_data2.Text);
                            TimeSpan horaentrega1 = TimeSpan.Parse(txt_hora2.Text);

                            data1 = data1.Add(hora1);
                            dataentrega1 = dataentrega1.Add(horaentrega1);

                            double horas1 = 0;
                            double minutos1 = 0;

                            for (var i = data1; i < dataentrega1; i = i.AddMinutes(1))
                            {
                                if (i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                                {
                                    if (i.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 9 && i.TimeOfDay.Hours <= 18)
                                    {
                                        if (i.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 13 && i.TimeOfDay.Hours < 14)
                                        {

                                        }

                                        else
                                        {
                                            minutos1++;

                                            for (var x = data1; x < dataentrega1; x = x.AddHours(1))
                                            {
                                                horas1 = (minutos1 / 60) + extra;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            TimeSpan tempo1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(horas1);

                            MySqlCommand UPDATE20 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_orcamentos SET tempo ='" + tempo1 + "'WHERE id ='" + txt_cod.Text + "'", ligar);
                            UPDATE20.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_datainicio.Text);
                        TimeSpan hora = TimeSpan.Parse(txt_horainicio.Text);
                        DateTime dataentrega = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_data2.Text);
                        TimeSpan horaentrega = TimeSpan.Parse(txt_hora2.Text);

                        data = data.Add(hora);
                        dataentrega = dataentrega.Add(horaentrega);

                        float horas = 0;
                        float minutos = 0;

                        for (var i = data; i < dataentrega; i = i.AddMinutes(1))
                        {
                            if (i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && i.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                            {
                                if (i.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 9 && i.TimeOfDay.Hours < 18)
                                {
                                    if (i.TimeOfDay.Hours >= 13 && i.TimeOfDay.Hours < 14)
                                    {

                                    }

                                    else
                                    {
                                        minutos++;

                                        for (var x = data; x < dataentrega; x = x.AddHours(1))
                                        {
                                            horas = minutos / 60;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        TimeSpan tempo = TimeSpan.FromHours(horas);                    

                        MySqlCommand UPDATE21 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE tbl_orcamentos SET tempo ='" + tempo + "'WHERE id ='" + txt_cod.Text + "'", ligar);
                        UPDATE21.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm using c# and a mysql database.

It seems to work but when the result was 48h, instead of "48:00:00", it's trying to update it to "2.00:00:00" which isn't valid as "tempo" it's a time field in mysql. I don't really know how to solve it and so far I've tried to make "horas" a datetime and then formatting it to the right format but it didn't work.

I'd really appreciate any help and I'm sorry if it's hard to understand, just ask and I'll try to explain further.

EDIT:

Adding the float "horas" which contains the number of hours into the Timespan:

```
TimeSpan tempo = TimeSpan.FromHours(horas);
```

Comment: can you reduce the code sample to _only_ show the relevant lines where you parse `48h` into a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: you cannot update a time column with the time bigger than 23:59:59, otherwise you need to change it to string type

Comment: I put the code line in the edit

Comment: So Time isn't for elapsed time but for hours in a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard SQL data type for a difference in time is "interval". MySQL doesn't support the "interval" data type.

It can be confusing, because times of day and intervals use the same notation, but have different meanings. The value '1:00' means 1 o'clock if it's a time of day ("time" or "timestamp"). But the same value means one hour if it's an interval.

Also, "48:00:00" is a valid interval (48 hours), but it's not a valid time of day.

If you're using MySQL, calculate and store the interval in an integer representing the number of hours, minutes, or seconds, and format for display. For example, store two hours as the integer 7200 (seconds) or as the integer 120 (minutes), depending on the application's requirements. Format that integer as "2:00" for display. C#'s `TimeSpan.FromMinutes` and `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` will help.

If you want to play around with an open source dbms that supports intervals, look at PostgreSQL.